# Hive query to rename a Hbase table

Tags: hive, hbase

Is there any Hive query using which i can rename Hbase table?

Comment: [`ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME TO new_table_name;`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RenameTable) ?

Comment: This is only working for Hive table. I need a query that work for Hive table which is stored in Hbase.(Hive mapping for Hbase table).

When i execute above query, following in error message is given,

"FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10134]: ALTER TABLE cannot be used for a non-native table hbase_table_7"

Answer (score 1):

No, Hive cannot rename a HBase Table. You have to use either HBase shell or HBase api to rename Table.
Here is documentation for it:
http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#table.rename